Push some changes to a branch that are identical to pending ones
Can we push some changes to a branch that are identical to pending ones without causing issues?
Say there are pending branches A, B, C, one revision in A is having issues being approved due to a non-IT dispute late in the process, but some revisions in B and C are dependent on other changes in A and were deemed critical.
Because we weren't expecting politics to be involved, we had pushed A as-is to main, but haven't updated production yet, e.g. git pull origin main.
Because B and C are critical, we manually modified production to include some of A, and all of B, and C! For sure, not best practices by any metric, but were we expecting a quick resolution, so we thought, just do it for now so we can get B and C out, we can fix it when they sort it out...
main branch: A, B, C pending
production server: A*, B, C changes made

When we do git status in production, it's showing a lot of revised files. All these changes are identical to A, B, and C except for omitting some of the revisions in A. These revised files are posing a maintenance problem.
It may take a long time before there's a resolution to A, so we'd like to clean up production. If we push all the current changes in production to main, will that cause a lot of merge conflicts? If there are whitespace differences, is there a way to push but ignore those?
Alternatively, is there a way to break up A into A1/A2, with A1 having the changes we need for B and C, and A2 the ones still pending? Unfortunately it is the case that there can be both A1 and A2 changes in the same file.
If the above are not possible, our last alternative is to create branch D with conditional code that checks if the environment is production and disables the disputed features in A, then update main and production with that.

“If the above are not possible, our last alternative is to create branch D with conditional code that checks if the environment is production and disables the disputed features in A, then update main and production with that.” Then do that? That is vastly more simple than picking things in and out of branches.

@Guildenstern - Thanks, I'm not well versed in git, so just needed confirmation that the other approaches would be harder.
